# Loud noise coming from laptop

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, fan, noise

A friend brought me his laptop, complaining that it sometimes makes a loud noise.  Sure enough, every once in a while, it makes a real loud noise.

There's only 2 moving parts in there: the hard drive and the fan.  SMART stats are fine, so I think it's probably the fan.

His laptop is only a few months old, so it's under warranty.  But it's a Toshiba, and so he'll have to pay for shipping and insurance and wait who-knows-how-long.

I'm thinking about just replacing the fan for him.  I've built *many* desktop computers, but I've never replaced a fan in a laptop.

Is it as trivial as it sounds, or are there important caveats and techniques involved?

*Update: After watching the video Steven provided in his answer, I'm concerned the noise could be coming from his hard drive.  The sound seems to be emanating from the front-right quadrant.*

Comment: 1. know what laptop it is. … oh… 2. tell **us** what laptop it is...

Comment: @Tetsujin Are you requesting the model number?  If so, I'll find out for you.

Comment: Get matching fan, open laptop, replace fan, close laptop. Otherwise all other normal computer repair procedures should be followed.  As-is this is too broad (IMO), as I'm not sure what your actual question to us is..

Comment: ermm… yeah - otherwise it's a bit general - 'don't lose the screws… don't break the cables... remember where everything went...'

Comment: @RockPaperLizard It's easy once you get the laptop opened to the point where the fan can be removed. Depending on the model, this can be easy or somewhat involved. You can probably manage if you can find instructions on how to open it though.

Comment: @Techie007 If it is that simple, then your answer is exactly the correct answer.  If it's more complicated, then it's not.  For example, replacing the fan in your vehicle is not that simple and is quite involved.

Comment: @Tetsujin  I got the model number.  His laptop is a Toshiba C55-B5272.

Comment: After watching the video Steven provided in his answer, I'm concerned the noise could be coming from his hard drive.  The sound seems to be emanating from the front-right quadrant.

Comment: While you're getting a lot of practical advice on disassembly, my concern would be the replacement of the fan.  Most likely the original fan is some obscure manufacturer and model number, for which you can find neither power consumption nor airflow characteristics, and hence cannot make a perfect replacement match (assuming you know what to do with such data).  Also, it's interesting that nobody seems curious as to the characteristics of this *"real loud noise"*, and to assess your conclusion that it must be the fan that needs replacement.

Comment: @sawdust I share both your concerns.  The last "laptop" I opened weighed over 25 lbs ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compaq_Portable ).

Comment: No one has mentioned the warranty. Understand that opening the laptop means voiding the manufacturer warranty. It's not worth it. If your friend needs it for work, his IT dept can provide a loaner. If it's for personal use, there needs to be the understanding that warranty repair and being without a computer is part of working with technology. Good luck.

Comment: @Alex Good point.  In this case, he's had horrible experiences with Toshiba trying to get them to fix obvious defects under warranty.  He said he will never buy a Toshiba laptop again because of those experiences.  He even wrote a letter to their corporate HQ, and they never replied.

Comment: Yea, I hear that a lot about Toshiba. I advise people to stick to Asus and Lenovo, or other premium brands like Gigabyte, MSI, and Razer. I'd love to get my hands on an Origin. Lenovo has to be awesome, their home user base is very close to their corporate clientele. The others are just crazy passionate, and it shows.

Comment: Clone the hard drive to a new one before it fails completely.

Answer (score 2):

First, diagnose which component.

Method 1: Remove the hard drive.  Power on the laptop.  Do you hear the sound?

Method 2: Use diagnostics software (often provided by the manufacturer) to stress the CPU or HDD, which may trigger the sound.

Second, replace the component.

Manufacturer's support sites *sometimes* provide documentation to replace certain components.

Also, check YouTube for a disassembly video for the laptop.  For a Toshiba C55-B5272, check out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=og7JdxuhF7M

Comment: Thanks for the video, Steven.   Very dramatic music!  After watching it, I'm concerned the noise could be coming from his hard drive.  The sound seems to be emanating from the front-right quadrant.

Comment: See my edit.  Remove the hard drive.  See if the sound goes away.

Comment: Thanks for your edit.  Unfortunately, the sound is so infrequent, it will be hard to diagnose it that way.  According to the owner, the sound only occurs one or two times per day.

Comment: Try to trigger the sound using hardware diagnostics software.